# switch between portrait and landscape

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i have taken two views one is portrait and landscape,i want the switch the view on rotation i am using below code but its not working,may i know where i am going wrong as i am new to iphone development.i have not implemented anything in ViewDidLoad method,should i implement anything there as well?

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        self.portrait.hidden = YES;
        self.landscape.hidden = NO;
    } else  {
        self.portrait.hidden = NO;
        self.landscape.hidden =YES;
    }

    return YES; 
}
```

Comment: tell me ur mail i have an very Good Tutorial. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have showed To Images in Two Views One in Horizontal and one in Vertical....
[image: A Sample View]

In ViewController.m:-

```
@interface OrientationTutorialViewController : UIViewController 
{

    IBOutlet UIView *portraitView;
    IBOutlet UIView *landscapeView;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *portraitView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *landscapeView;


@end
```

IN .h :-

```
@implementation OrientationTutorialViewController

@synthesize portraitView, landscapeView;


- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];

}

- (void) orientationChanged:(id)object
{  
    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[object object] orientation];

    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) 
    {
        self.view = self.portraitView;
    } 
    else 
    {
        self.view = self.landscapeView;
    }
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    return YES;
}



- (void)dealloc 
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Hope My Answer Helps You... If Not Please Tell me ur id I will Send u the Project.

Comment: Hey Have u received my Mail... Is this answer helped you..??

Answer (score 0):

To support orientation the function

```
-(Bool)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation    {
     return YES;

 }
```

Now to perform the action while rotation you have to use the below function

As you have two views named landscape and portrait make sure that you have linked Referencing outlets correctly

```
    -(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{


if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) 
{

    self.view = portrait;



}
else
{
    self.view = landscape;


}

}
```

Comment: in landscape logic i am writing  self.view = self.landscape; and in portrait vice versa but on rotation its not getting changed i want all four rotation

Comment: in the landscape login you dont have to do self.view=self.landscape. changing the view is automatically handled by the device.you should make sure that your all ViewController have the "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" function and it should only return YES no other coding in it.

Comment: ya i know that.Now i have taken two views and named it has portrait and landscape.in a view i have some UI design done on both the views.so on rotation i want the views to be switched respectively.so what i should add in the above code.In landscape and portrait logic.

Comment: i changed to above code but on rotation its not changing.Note this class is under Appdelegate class i have added a new file class of UIViewcontroller so do i need to implement anyth in ViewDidLoad method??

Comment: this all logic should be in your new ViewController class that you have added. are you doing the same?? nit should not be in the Appdelegate class

Comment: ya logic above is in new class only.But on rotation its not changing only initial whether landscape or portrait it works fine.but on rotation its not.

Comment: have you linked corresponding referencing outlets..of the two view that you have created.i.e. portrait and landscpe

Comment: on rotation it doesnt change..on rotaion from landscape to portrait still it remains landscape image itself.its not switching

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        self.portrait.hidden = YES;
        self.landscape.hidden = NO;

        return YES;
    }
    else {
        self.portrait.hidden = NO;
        self.landscape.hidden = YES;

        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MisterJack But i hv two views named as portrait and landscape.i want to switch them on rotation

Comment: @crazy2431 I've only corrected the formatting of this answer.